# Getting CORS errors even when using --proxy setting in Ember Server

Tags: cors, ember-cli

I am running Ember Server as follows:
ember server --proxy https://www.example.com

Here is the error that I am getting in the Ember inspector:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.example.com/users. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

localhost:4200 needs to specify that www.example.com is allowed to make requests, or whitelist all domains.  Here is what those two headers would look like:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.example.com
```

or

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Note that * is not best practice

Comment: How do I configure this in Ember Server?

Comment: @PeterS you don't configure this in Ember Server, you configure it on your backend services. For example, I use Spring and setup a CORS filter that processes each request and sets the appropriate headers.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed the problem. Basically, if you set the host property in your RESTAdapter, proxying will fail. I had this setting:

```
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: https://example.com
});
```

Which killed the --proxy parameter in Ember Server. I removed that line and it all works now.